# if is within sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I have several sidebars (more then 1 on a page) and I would like to set different image sizes to widgets, depending in which sidebar they are located.

I tried

```
if( ! dynamic_sidebar('my-sidebar') ) :
```

and

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) :
```

but this only seems to check if the sidebar's exist (and they do).

How do I get:
"**if widget is located in sidebar A, give me this size,
elseif widget is located in sidebar B, give me that size**"?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Here I have registered 2 sidebars in functions.php with names *sidebar1* and *sidebar2*.

```
$sidebar_args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'sidebar1', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' );

register_sidebar( $sidebar_args );


$sidebar_args_2 = array(
    'name'          => __( 'sidebar2', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
    'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' );

register_sidebar( $sidebar_args_2 );
```

And now retrieving their names on theme's page like this.

```
<?php
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
    $my_sidebars = $wp_registered_sidebars;

    foreach($my_sidebars as $my_sidebar){
        echo $my_sidebar['name'];
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you so much!
get_my_widgets(); is not doing anything in my theme (I did put the function in my functions.php like you said).
Could you give me an example of the output it should give?

Comment: I have edited the code. Check now.